# Make Firebug NOT autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, firebug

I just started using Firebug, and the autocompletion feature is proving to be more a nuisance than an asset. The issue is that on some web pages there are elements whose names start with numbers, so that if I go to Firebug's console and type something like `a=1`, it will autocomplete to something I don't want.  Since <kbd>Enter</kbd> selects the autocompletion, there doesn't seem to be a good way to *not* choose to autocomplete.

The best solution to this that I've come up with so far is to put some whitespace after my desired command. I'm looking for a better solution. In particular:

1. Is there another key besides <kbd>Enter</kbd> which will submit a command to the console, without accepting an autocompletion suggestion?
2. Is there a way to reconfigure the autocompleter so that <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not select a suggestion (since <kbd>Tab</kbd> does the same thing, I see no need to have <kbd>Enter</kbd> also select suggestions...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in Firebug - I opened https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7729 for it and pushed a fix.

As for your question, no, there is no way to make it not auto-complete other than (as you note) adding additional whitespace, or pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> before <kbd>Enter</kbd> (this also serves as a revert key when you accidentally do auto-complete, FWIW). The reasoning is that any situation where it would be annoying is a bug, so adding a pref or way to avoid it would be admitting failure, in a sense.